# For certain registry path/key, I'm not getting data

Tags: c#, registry

I am using below code and for `SOFTWARE\\Intel\\Bluetooth\\Metrics` and `Version` I'm NOT getting data. What's the reason?

[image]

```
 ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions();
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\default", oConn);

            scope.Connect();
            ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
            inParams["sSubKeyName"] = "SOFTWARE\\Intel\\Bluetooth\\Metrics";
            inParams["hDefKey"] = 0x80000002;
            inParams["sValueName"] = "Version";


            ManagementBaseObject outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);

            if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString());
            }
```

**Note -** With above code for `SOFTWARE\\ASIO\\Realtek ASIO` and `Description`, I am getting data. Why certain registry path/key NOT works?

[image]

```
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = "SOFTWARE\\ASIO\\Realtek ASIO";
            inParams["hDefKey"] = 0x80000002;
            inParams["sValueName"] = "Description";
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that you're running as a 32 bit process and you've not taken account of 64/32 bit registry redirection...

Comment: how to add this check? how to do  64/32 bit registry redirection

Comment: It's not a check, it's a [read and understand what the registry redirector does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/registry-redirector), then *decide* what you want to do.

Comment: where I need to put `RegistryView.Registry64`

Comment: I can't tell you immediately. It's unclear why you're using management objects rather than the built in Registry classes in the framework.

Comment: basically I need to remote machine registry and I have to pass machine IP and credential. `OpenRemoteBaseKey` doesn't support it

Comment: `ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions
                    {
                        Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
                        Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
                        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                        Username = username,
                        Password = password
                    };

                    scope = new ManagementScope($"\\\\{ipAddress}\\root\\default", connectionOptions);
                    scope.Connect();`